# How to find the domain name on which the website is hosted

Tags: php

I am searching for the exact counter `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` which could let me know on which domain name the site is getting visited. For portability reason i cannot use hard coded domain names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`